# Journey into a strange wilderness

Tags: soft-question, gm.general-mathematics

W. S. Anglin wrote

*Mathematics is not a careful march down a well-cleared highway, but a journey into a strange wilderness, where the explorers often get lost. Rigour should be a signal to the historian that the maps have been made, and the real explorers have gone elsewhere.*

What wildernesses are being explored these days and by whom?

Comment: Historically, Newton, Euler, Fourier, Heaviside, and Riemann were iconic explorers blazing trails through strange widernesses, but today ... ?

Comment: I think at present this is far too broad.

Answer (score -1):

The [landscape of string theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory_landscape) is aptly characterized as a "wilderness" for mathematicians.

*"String theory is a piece of 21st-century physics that has fallen by accident into the 20th century and therefore will require 22nd-century mathematics to solve."*
<sub>Daniele Amati</sub>

See also [The mathematics of string theory](http://www.bourbaphy.fr/dijkgraaf.pdf) by Robbert Dijkgraaf.

Comment: Who is Daniele Amati? A great deal of 20th century physics was solved with 20th century mathematics.. think of quantum mechanics or general relativity

Comment: [Daniele Amati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniele_Amati) was referring to string theory, which seems out of reach of presently available mathematical tools.

Comment: What would it mean to "solve" string theory?

Comment: @Wojowu --- perhaps in the sense that the [anti-de Sitter/conformal field theory correspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdS/CFT_correspondence) "solves" string theory on a manifold of constant negative curvature.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker notice that we are in 2020. New insights are gained every day. It is perfectly possible that in 30 years, say, there will be a rigorous theory of the Feynman integral/infinite-dimensional integration, etc...

Comment: Certainly one of the first to spring to mind, with Witten as one of the explorers.